# Ignoring warnings of a third-party library in GCC

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, qmake

In the software project I'm working on, we use certain 3rd party libraries which, sadly, produce annoying gcc warnings. I am using Qt Creator v 4.2.1 (based on Qt 5.8) as IDE and my OS and gcc version is Linux (mint distribution v 17.1) and 4.8.4 respectively. I am trying to clean all warnings. One of the best ways to do is the "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS" in .pro file of my project like below:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $$(LIBRARY_HOME)/include/hpp
```

As you can see above, I used "-isystem" for ignoring warning of third-party library ([GCC Directory Option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Directory-Options.html)). But the directory path is somehow strange. There is not any header file in this folder. Instead all headers are in the following path:

```
$$(LIBRARY_HOME)/include/hpp/headers
```

Surprisingly, if you modify the path to this one, it does not work and all warning come again!!! So I'm wondering how it works.

In addition, if you have both header file (".h") and implementation file (".cpp") in a directory and add its path to QMAKE_CXXFLAGS for ignoring warnings, it does not work.

Thanks in advance for your helps.